# XMLStarlet Error: xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node: out of memory

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I get an error while trying to parse an xml using xmlstarlet.

```
-:1.13408001: xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node: out of memory

SSWMgg5MqED5Tjk9jjkda0P2fLNLrxNrmp3CsbqGNFDdAPMLFsj6oPpzX0C6GSGVBjLKRz0oSVh3fQ+f ^ -:1.13408001: Extra content at the end of the document SSWMgg5MqED5Tjk9jjkda0P2fLNLrxNrmp3CsbqGNFDdAPMLFsj6oPpzX0C6GSGVBjLKRz0oSVh3fQ+f
```

Any suggestions on how I can handle this error? Or, ignore the tag causing this problem and move on to the next node?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume it has something to do with that: `out of memory`.

Comment: hey, yes. The xml file has base64 coded attachments that are huge in size. I want to ignore them and not fail. Any ideas?

Comment: Use [xmllint](https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/discussion/226076/thread/2fab1f7da8/)?

Comment: That'll be a lot of work for me. I'll have to get it installed on all my servers. Do you know if xmllint works in this case?

Comment: You could try using StAX instead, which is a stream parser that does not load the entire file but hands you events for each node.  I haven't used StAX in a decade, so I don't know if you can skip a text node without reading it into memory.  Also, you'd need to be able to identify the nodes containing the large blobs at the "start element" event.

Comment: @Invalidsearch: I have no experience with the `--huge` option in the context of `xmllint`.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I made a [patch](https://github.com/martin7th/xmlstarlet-patch-huge/) to make `xmlstarlet`
use 'huge' nodes and 'big lines'. It requires the program to be rebuilt
from source code.

Quoting from the README:

> This patch adds 2 global options to [`xmlstarlet`](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/),
> available in the subcommands `elements`, `select`, `edit`, `format`,
> `canonic`, `validate`, and `transform`:
>
> - `--huge`
>   Load XML files with [`libxml2`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/wikis/home)'s `XML_PARSE_HUGE`
>   parser option. Without this option the parser will fail with a
>   "xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node: out of memory" error when
>   loading a text node larger than 10 MB. (`xmlstarlet`'s `pyx`
>   subcommand uses the SAX API which has no such limitation.)
>   In `libxml2` the `XML_PARSE_HUGE` option is disabled by default to
>   prevent denial-of-service attacks.
> - `--big-lines`
>   Load XML files with `libxml2`'s `XML_PARSE_BIG_LINES` parser option.
>   This allows line numbers larger than 65535 to be reported correctly
>   in error messages and (for `select` and `transform`) in output from
>   the `saxon:line-number` extension.
>   There is currently an open [issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/issues/361) on this option
>   suggesting it's limited to text nodes, however, it appears to have
>   been resolved by now as line numbers are output as expected for all
>   node types except the root node (`/`) which is fixed at line `-1`.

Comment: I'm working on Windows no hope to have this patch working here?

Comment: @user3680029 If you have `cygwin` installed you should be able to compile it: the 2 libraries should be in [`libxml2-devel`](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/libxml2-devel.html)
and [`libxslt-devel`](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/libxslt-devel.html). However, I haven't worked on Windows in ages so there's not much I can do to guide you.